# How to set cell value from google sheet as default value of textarea for HTML sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a standalone Google script using as library. This library contains HTML form using like sidebar with one `<textarea>` element and scripts. I want to get some value from a cell of active google spreadsheet to set it as default value of `<textarea>` element in the sidebar. And then update it with manually typing text and send it as new value to the source cell keeping sidebar is open.

Library's scripts

```js
function showSidebar() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('method.html')
        .setTitle('Cooking method')
        .setWidth(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
        .showSidebar(html);
  }

function addNewMethod(form_data)
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//modified 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Method');
  var cookingMethod = form_data.method;   
  sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(cookingMethod);
}

function getDefaultMethod() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Method');
  const currentMethod = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
  return currentMethod

}
```

HTML sidebar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function()
      {
         google.script.run
             .withSuccessHandler(updateMethod)
             .getDefaultMethod();
      });
      function updateMethod(method_val)
      {
         document.getElementById('method').innerHTML=method_val;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="mysidebar">
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="method"></label>
        <textarea id="method" name="method" rows="30" cols="40">
        </textarea>
    </div>   

    <div class="block">
    <button type="submit" class="action">Add cooking method</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    document.querySelector("#mysidebar").addEventListener("submit", 
    function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().addNewMethod(this);
    }
    )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

functions on the client spreadsheet. Library's name is `RecipeBuilder`

````js
```
function showSidebar() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('method.html')
    .setTitle('Cooking method')
    .setWidth(900);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showSidebar(html);
  }

function addNewMethod(form_data)
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Method');
  var cookingMethod = form_data.method;   
  sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(cookingMethod);
}

function getDefaultMethod() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Method');
  const currentMethod = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
  return currentMethod

}
```
````

My script does not work. Sidebar appears with blank `<textarea>` and does not send updated value to the cell.
Where I'm wrong and how to fix it? Can I make sidebar more widely then 300?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the value retrieved from the cell "A2" of the `Method` sheet in the active Spreadsheet as the default value for `textarea`.
- When the "Add cooking method" button is clicked, you want to retrieve the values from `textarea` and put the values to the cell "A2" of the `Method` sheet in the active Spreadsheet.
- You want to know the reason of the issue of `Sidebar appears with blank <textarea> and does not send updated value to the cell.`.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- About `getDefaultMethod()` in the client side, in your script, it is required to return the value from `RecipeBuilder.getDefaultMethod()`. In your current script, the value is not returned. So when the HTML is loaded, the value retrieved from the cell "A2" of the `Method` sheet in the active Spreadsheet is not set to `textarea`.
- About `addNewMethod()` in the GAS library side, `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet;` is not run the method. So please add `()`.

  - I think that this is the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

Please modify `getDefaultMethod()` of the client side as follows.

From:

```
function getDefaultMethod(){
  RecipeBuilder.getDefaultMethod();
}
```

To:

```
function getDefaultMethod(){
  return RecipeBuilder.getDefaultMethod();  // Modified
}
```

And, please modify `addNewMethod()` of the GAS library side as follows.

From:

```
function addNewMethod(form_data)
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Method');
  var cookingMethod = form_data.method;   
  sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(cookingMethod);
}
```

To:

```
function addNewMethod(form_data)
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Modified
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Method');
  var cookingMethod = form_data.method;   
  sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(cookingMethod);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script, if the client side is NOT the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet and the Google Spreadsheet of client side doesn't have the sheet of `Method`, an error occurs. So please be careful this.

Comment: Sorry. Its does not work. Sidebar appears with empty text field and not submits updates

Comment: Maybe it's the problem in HTML of sidebar?

Comment: @Timogavk Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that the modified script worked. So I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide the script for completely replicating your issue by updating your question? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Timogavk What I want to ask is as follows. When I saw your updated question, I have one question. What is the script below `functions on the client spreadsheet. Library's name is RecipeBuilder`? I couldn't understand about it. Where can I see the script for replicating your current issue?