# How to change values in cell of Google Sheet from custom HTML sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with custom sidebar. Sidebar contains a form with `<textarea>` only.
The `<textarea>` takes value from table cell with script.
I want to send new value from sidebar to the same cell by `onchange` trigger or keep old value in the cell if it's not changed by user.
You can see below what I have. Unfortunately it does not work. Does not work means the sidebar takes value from the cell but don't send new one after changing. I don't understand why where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

```js
function showSidebar() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Change.html')
        .setTitle('Cooking method')
        .setWidth(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .showSidebar(html);
  }

function addNewMethod(form_data)
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Method');
  var cookingMethod = form_data.method;   
  sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(cookingMethod);
}

function getDefaultMethod() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Method');
  const currentMethod = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
  return currentMethod

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>change</title>
  <style>
   body{
   background-color: #3366CC;
   } 
   textarea {
   margin: 10px
   }
  </style>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function()
      {
         google.script.run
             .withSuccessHandler(updateMethod)
             .getDefaultMethod();
      });
      function updateMethod(method_val)
      {
         document.getElementById('method').innerHTML=method_val;
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="mysidebar">
    <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="method"></label>
        <textarea id="method" name="method" rows="30" cols="45">
        </textarea>
    </div>   
    </form>
<div></div>
<script>
         $("method").change(function () {
         google.script.run.addNewMethod(this);
         }).change();

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Can I ask you about the detail of `it does not work`? 2. How will you do about [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61570211/7108653)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's does not work from library (I'll fix it later). But works well with native spread sheet. Now I understood that I don't need button to submit form. It would be better to get new value when user change text in sidebar. Each spreadsheet will contain `Method` sheet to apply this sidebar.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `(I'll fix it later)`, I could understand. About your this question, in this case, the GAS script and HTML are put in one GAS project of the container-bound script without using a library?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding first comment. 1. `Does not work` for this question means `<textarea>` takes value from the cell but do not send new value when I change text in sidebar. 2. For my previous question - Unfortunately, it's does not work from library (I'll fix it later).

Comment: About container-bound script. I need to make too many copies of template spreadsheet. Each copy will copy container-bound script also. So in case when I need to modify my main script I will need to update each copy. It will be super complicated for 1000+ spreadsheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1. In your this question, the GAS script and HTML are put in one GAS project of the container-bound script without using a library? 2. I cannot understand about the relationship between your question and `About container-bound script. I need to make too many copies of template spreadsheet. Each copy will copy container-bound script also. So in case when I need to modify my main script I will need to update each copy. It will be super complicated for 1000+ spreadsheets`.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. I explained the reason why I want to use library for my previous question

Comment: Thank you for replying. About 1, I could understand about your this question. So I proposed a modification point. Could you please confirm it? About 2, I cannot still understand about it. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to send the value of textarea to `addNewMethod` of Google Apps Script.
- When you changed the textarea and remove the focus, you want to send it to GAS side.
- In your this situation, you don't use the Google Apps Script library. The GAS and HTML file are put in one GAS project of the container-bound script.

For this, how about this modification?

At first, please check whether my understanding of your this question is correct.

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify your HTML&Javascript as follows. In this modification, as a simple modification, I didn't modify your Google Apps Script side.

From:

```
$("method").change(function () {
google.script.run.addNewMethod(this);
}).change();
```

To:

```
$("#method").change(function () {
  const obj = {method: $("#method").val()};
  google.script.run.addNewMethod(obj);
});
```

- In this case, in order to run `google.script.run`, please remove the focus from the textarea after you inputted values.